# How to replace a new imageIcon?

Tags: java, image, swing, imageicon

```
String mycon="image1.png";

public LottoGUI(String one, String two,String three) {
    Container C= getContentPane();
    C.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JLabel MyImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(mycon));
    JButton labb =    new JButton("OK!");
    labb.addActionListener(this);
    C.add(MyImage);
    C.add(labb) 
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==labb){}
}
```

How do I change the picture from **image1** to **a new image** when I press the button?

Answer (score 2):

1) Try using the `setIcon` method. If this does not work, 2) Replace
the whole `JLabel` object with a new one (which has the new icon).

[JLabel setIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29)

If using the 2nd approach, you need to
turn the `MyImage` into a class variable.

Answer (score 2):

**Slightly off-topic**

You should not be loading your images from a the file system. When you pass a path String the the `ImageIcon`, you are ultimately telling it to look for the image within the file system. Though this may work during development time in your IDE, you will find that at time of deployment, it *will not* work.

Instead you should be loading the image as a [**embedded resource**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) via a URL. A URL can be obtained using [`Class.getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29). The resource will be looked up from the class path, as it should. Here is an example

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(MyClass.class.getResource("/resources/image.png"));
```

Where the `image.png` is located in this a resources package in the the `src`, which will get copied into the class path upon build

```
ProjectRoot
          src
              resources
                      image.png
```

---

**Back on-topic**

As for your main question, as @peter.petrov noted, you should be using `.setIcon(icon);` and make `MyImage` a class member with a global scope, so it can be accessed in other code blocks. Right now it is only scoped locally in the constructor

```
String mycon="image1.png";
JLabel MyImage;

public LottoGUI(String one, String two,String three) {
    Container C= getContentPane();
    C.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    MyImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(mycon));
    JButton labb =    new JButton("OK!");
    labb.addActionListener(this);
    C.add(MyImage);
    C.add(labb) 
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==labb){
        MyImage.setIcon(newIcon);
    }
}
```

---

Also note Java naming convention. variable should begin with lowercase letters i.e. `MyImage` should be `myImage`

Answer (score 1):

Use this Line on JButton click Event

```
jLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/one.png")));
```

Replace `"/images/one.png"` with your class path..

Thnaks..